# What will happen with my app if I not get permission from FB to use "publish permissions"

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a iOS application with more that 20k users. All current app versions are asking for publish permissions from user, but I never used it.

I'm already working on new version without this permissions, but I wonder what will happen with my app after April 30, 2015 without FB review? I don't have to go thru it if I'll remove publish permission from my app.

User can be still able to log in using facebook?

Mariusz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to ask Facebook if there are any issues (or check the FB docs)

Comment: If you request a permission that is not approved, the login dialog will simply not ask the user for that permission.

Comment: @wain facebook reffers do StackOverflow as a place to ask questions like this :( There is no other way to contact with FB Dev Support.

Comment: What about https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What will happen after April 30th, 2015 is that the login dialog won't show this permission anymore to people who are not in the roles tab of your Facebook Application Dashboard Settings (meaning the general public).

If you are 100% sure you are not using this permission, you should be good to go. It is great you're already creating a version with this stripped. Remember to remove it from your Facebook Application Dashboard Settings as well.

If for some reason, you are using this permission (Any Graph API or Facebook Dialog to publish), your Facebook Integration will be broken.

More information can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#pre-f8-apps